# Close one form and display another

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

My app starts with a `LoginForm` where the user will enter their credentials. I need to close the `LoginForm` and display the `DashboardForm`. I'm able to do this:

```
public static bool OpenDashboardFormOnClose { get; set; }
public static bool OpenLoginFormOnClose { get; set; }

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    OpenDashboardFormOnClose = false;
    OpenLoginFormOnClose = false;

    Application.Run(new LoginForm());

    if (OpenDashboardFormOnClose)
    {
        Application.Run(new DashboardForm());
    }           

    if (OpenLoginFormOnClose)
    {
        Application.Run(new LoginForm());
    }
}
```

The `LoginForm` login method:

```
Program.OpenDashboardFormOnClose = true;
this.Close();
```

The `DashboardForm` logout method:

```
Program.OpenLoginFormOnClose = true;
this.Close();
```

This works great when the user just logs in and then logs out.
The issue is that when a user has just logged out, and they try to log in again, the app closes instead of displaying the `DashboardForm`.
How do I achieve this? The user should be able to login and out as many times as they want...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is less about coding and more about what you want to happen, of course you cant read the users mind. so what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really recommend to use this approach of using many `Application.Run` one after another to show consecutive forms. That method starts the main message loop of the program, and generally is run once at program start and returns only once, at program exit.

Instead, make the forms open each other as needed, and leave the main message loop alone. Let's modify it to return to its almost default state:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    //Open the initial formm I'm assuming it's the login
    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
    loginForm.Show();

    //Start the main message loop for the whole lifetime of the program
    Application.Run();
}
```

Now, on the login form, when it's time to dismiss it and launch the main form, it does it itself instead of delegating:

```
//Close itself
this.Close();
//Launch the next form
DashboardForm dashboardForm = new DashboardForm();
dashboardForm.Show();
```

Similarly, on the dashboard when logging out you'll need to relaunch the login:

```
//Close itself
this.Close();
//Show the login again
LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
loginForm.Show();
```

While all this work, this generates a problem not present before. As the main `Application.Run` isn't tied to a form, it won't stop running once the initial login exists, but only when explictly instructed to do so, with the net result of the process hanging after the window being closed.

To fix it, when it's time to close the application for good (not launch another form), call `Application.Exit();`, maybe in the `Form.Closing` event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when `this.Close()` for the `LoginForm` is called, `Application.Exit()` is also called which just closes the app. Any idea on how to work around this?

Comment: You could set a flag indicating if you closed the form yourself to avoid shutting down the whole application too early, and call `Application.Exit()` only if you didn't close the form programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `while` loop to display the login and dashboard forms repeatedly.  You won't need the "OpenLoginFormOnClose" flag anymore, but will need one to track whether the application should exit instead:

```
static class Program
{

    public static bool OpenDashboardFormOnClose;
    public static bool ExitApplication = false;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        while(!ExitApplication)
        {
            OpenDashboardFormOnClose = false;
            Application.Run(new LoginForm());
            if (OpenDashboardFormOnClose)
            {
                Application.Run(new DashboardForm());
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Then add an "exit" button to your form(s) that does:

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.ExitApplication = true;
    this.Close();
}
```

So now the while loop will drop out and your program will end.

Answer (score 0):

1. `this.Close` or `Close` just closes the current form, but if it's the main form it
   closes all of them.
2. `Application.Exit()` Closes all the windows from the same program.
3. There is **no** possible way to just close the main form. if you do it all the windows
   opened from it will close. You can only **hide** the form.

To hide the form, check the code below **▼**

```
private void Example_Click(object sender, EventArgs, e)
{
    this.Hide();
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
}
```

if you're on the dashboard form, and want to close all remaining windows with/or from it use **▼**

```
Application.Exit();
```

Another even simpler way many people don't use to open a form **▼**

```
new DashBoardForm().Show();
```